# Tipo dos elementos de uma lista - Python

Tags: python, lista, tipo-de-conteúdo

Eu tenho duas listas de tamanhos diferentes. A primeira é uma lista de listas.
Onde eu preciso comparar o tipo dos elementos dessa primeira lista de listas com outra lista que contém tipo de dados (str, int, float,..).

Exemplo:

```
lista1 = [['a', 'bb', 1.5, 3, 'a'],['h', 'oo', 9.6, 2, 'n'],...,['u', 'pp', 2.9, 1, 'j']]

lista2 = ['str', 'str', 'float', 'int', 'str']
```

Eu estou fazendo assim:

```
for linha in range(0,68):
    for linha2 in range(0,11):
        if(type(lista1[linha2][linha]) != lista2[linha]):
            print("Alguma coisa")
```

Mas não está dando certo, porque retorna:

> `int, <class 'int'>`

Então não reconhece como igual e sim como diferente. Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como a ***lista2*** vem preenchida com os nomes de tipos de dados do seu banco de dados não podemos fazer a conversão direta, vamos ter que criar um dicionário que fará o "de->para" dos tipos do banco para os tipos do Python.

Veja como ficaria:

```
lista1 = [['a', 'bb', 1.5, 3, 'a'],['h', 'oo', 9.6, 2, 'n'],...,['u', 'pp', 2.9, 1, 'j']]

# Adequando a lista2 para a situação
# lista2 = ['str', 'str', 'float', 'int', 'str']
lista2 = ['char', 'varchar', 'float', 'int', 'char']

# Dicionário de "de->para" do label que vem do banco para o tipo em Python 
tipo = {'int': int, 'nvarchar': str, 'varchar': str, 'char': str, 'decimal': float, 'decimal': float, 'float': float}

for linha in range(68): # quando o range começa com 0 não é preciso declará-lo
    for linha2 in range(11):

        # Estou criando as variáveis aqui para deixar o IF mais limpo
        typeLista1 = type(lista1[linha2][linha])
        typeLista2 = tipo[lista2[linha]] 

        if typeLista1 is not typeLista2:
            print("Alguma coisa")
```

Eu apenas alterei seu próprio exemplo para demonstrar minha ideia, se você quiser detalhar melhor sua necessidade eu posso alterar meu código para deixá-lo mais próximo da sua necessidade real.

Abraço.

Comment: A primeira lista vem de um banco de dados e a segunda vem de um Excel. O que eu estou fazendo é um Data Quality, então preciso validar se o tipo dos dados do banco de dados é o mesmo que eles deveriam ser (que vem do excel).

Comment: @Sjokolade então é simples, basta voltar a `lista2` para `string` e alterar essa linha:  
`if type(lista1[linha2][linha]) is not lista2[linha]):`  
para:  
`if type(lista1[linha2][linha]) is not eval(lista2[linha])):`  
Abraço

Comment: Funcionou, mas teve um problema, o Python não reconhece nvarchar e varchar como no SQL. Então precisaria alterar para string. Certo? Tem como fazer isso dinamicamente?

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, você pega os tipos de dados do banco de dados, portanto a nomenclatura dos tipos de dados não deve bater 100% com o Python, certo?

Eu penso que daria para montar um dicionário de conversão, se você me passar os tipos que você usa eu posso montar pra você e depois você vai ampliando conforme sua necessidade futura.

Comment: Isso! Eu uso int, nvarchar, varchar, char, decimal, numeric e float.

Comment: Veja se estou certo: "int" = int, "nvarchar" = str, "varchar" = str, "char" = str, "decimal" = float, "numeric" = float e "float" = float. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Exatamente isso!

Comment: Deu certo? Quando você conseguir chegar na solução não esqueça de indicar aqui, sua solução deve ajudar mais gente que tem a mesma dúvida. Obrigado.

Comment: Deu sim, desculpa pela demora!! Ficou assim: ConversaoTipos = {'int': int, 'nvarchar': str, 'varchar': str, 'char': str, 'decimal': float, 'numeric': float, 'float': float}
if type(lista1[linha2][linha]) is (ConversaoTipos[lista2[linha]]): print("Alguma coisa")

Comment: Beleza. Da um UP na resposta e marca ela como a sua solução, isso aí vai indicar aos demais usuários qual foi a solução que você usou e vai dar uma forcinha na minha reputação. Abraço

Comment: Obrigada! Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Olha amigo, eu fiz esse aqui às pressas :

```
lista1 = [['a', 'bb', 1.5, 3, 'a'],['h', 'oo', 9.6, 2, 'n'],['u', 'pp', 2.9, 1, 'j']]

lista2 = ['str', 'float', 'int']

for linha in lista1:
    for linha2 in range(len(linha)):
        tipo = str(type(linha[linha2])).replace("<class '",'') # Retiro [ <class ' ]
        tipo = tipo.replace("'>",'') #retiro [ '> ], ficando só o tipo [ str, float ou int ]
        if tipo in lista2: # Se tiveer outro tipo além de str, float ou int, ele não será exibido.
            print(str(linha[linha2]).ljust(3),'=', tipo)
```

saida :

```
a   = str
bb  = str
1.5 = float
3   = int
a   = str
h   = str
oo  = str
9.6 = float
2   = int
n   = str
u   = str
pp  = str
2.9 = float
1   = int
j   = str
```